# Elasticsearch fuzzy queries ignores boost factor?

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

When I run this query:

```
GET /index_for_test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query":       "Italian",
            "type":        "most_fields",
            "fields":      [ "name^2", "categories" ],
        }
    }
}
```

it shows this result:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.04012554,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "index_for_test",
            "_type": "business",
            "_id": "1269493995",
            "_score": 0.04012554,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Bono Italian Restaurant",
               "categories": [
                  "Pizza"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "index_for_test",
            "_type": "business",
            "_id": "2017788160",
            "_score": 0.014542127,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Pizza Perperook",
               "categories": [
                  "Italian Food"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

But when I add fuzziness to this query:

```
GET /index_for_test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query":       "Italian",
            "type":        "most_fields",
            "fields":      [ "name^2", "categories" ],
            "fuzziness":2
        }
    }
}
```

it will ignores boost factor and shows this result:

```
{
   "took": 28,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.095891505,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "index_for_test",
            "_type": "business",
            "_id": "2017788160",
            "_score": 0.095891505,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Pizza Perperook",
               "categories": [
                  "Italian Food"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "index_for_test",
            "_type": "business",
            "_id": "1269493995",
            "_score": 0.076713204,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Bono Italian Restaurant",
               "categories": [
                  "Pizza"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

As I boost name field twice (by using name^2 as field) it should show same result as first query but it seems it ignores boost factor.

I use other types of query (query_string, fuzzy_like_this) and got same problem with them.

**edited:**

```
GET /index_for_test/_search?explain=true
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query":       "پیتزا",
            "type":        "most_fields",
            "fields":      [ "name^2", "categories" ]
        }
    }
}
```

result for fuzzy search with ?explain=true:

```
{
   "took": 25,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 0.05015693,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_shard": 1,
            "_node": "ZTZ37EpAR1W9e4Qqwk0O5Q",
            "_index": "index_for_test",
            "_type": "business",
            "_id": "2017788160",
            "_score": 0.05015693,
            "_source": {
               "name": "پیتزا پرپروک",
               "categories": [
                  "غذای ایتالیایی"
               ]
            },
            "_explanation": {
               "value": 0.05015693,
               "description": "product of:",
               "details": [
                  {
                     "value": 0.10031386,
                     "description": "sum of:",
                     "details": [
                        {
                           "value": 0.10031386,
                           "description": "weight(name:پیتزا^2.0 in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                           "details": [
                              {
                                 "value": 0.10031386,
                                 "description": "score(doc=0,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
                                 "details": [
                                    {
                                       "value": 0.5230591,
                                       "description": "queryWeight, product of:",
                                       "details": [
                                          {
                                             "value": 2,
                                             "description": "boost"
                                          },
                                          {
                                             "value": 0.30685282,
                                             "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)"
                                          },
                                          {
                                             "value": 0.8522964,
                                             "description": "queryNorm"
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "value": 0.19178301,
                                       "description": "fieldWeight in 0, product of:",
                                       "details": [
                                          {
                                             "value": 1,
                                             "description": "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                             "details": [
                                                {
                                                   "value": 1,
                                                   "description": "termFreq=1.0"
                                                }
                                             ]
                                          },
                                          {
                                             "value": 0.30685282,
                                             "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)"
                                          },
                                          {
                                             "value": 0.625,
                                             "description": "fieldNorm(doc=0)"
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "value": 0.5,
                     "description": "coord(1/2)"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_shard": 2,
            "_node": "ZTZ37EpAR1W9e4Qqwk0O5Q",
            "_index": "index_for_test",
            "_type": "business",
            "_id": "1269493995",
            "_score": 0.023267403,
            "_source": {
               "name": "رستوران ایتالیایی بونو",
               "categories": [
                  "پیتزا"
               ]
            },
            "_explanation": {
               "value": 0.023267403,
               "description": "product of:",
               "details": [
                  {
                     "value": 0.046534806,
                     "description": "sum of:",
                     "details": [
                        {
                           "value": 0.046534806,
                           "description": "weight(categories:پیتزا in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                           "details": [
                              {
                                 "value": 0.046534806,
                                 "description": "score(doc=0,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
                                 "details": [
                                    {
                                       "value": 0.15165187,
                                       "description": "queryWeight, product of:",
                                       "details": [
                                          {
                                             "value": 0.30685282,
                                             "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)"
                                          },
                                          {
                                             "value": 0.49421698,
                                             "description": "queryNorm"
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "value": 0.30685282,
                                       "description": "fieldWeight in 0, product of:",
                                       "details": [
                                          {
                                             "value": 1,
                                             "description": "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                             "details": [
                                                {
                                                   "value": 1,
                                                   "description": "termFreq=1.0"
                                                }
                                             ]
                                          },
                                          {
                                             "value": 0.30685282,
                                             "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)"
                                          },
                                          {
                                             "value": 1,
                                             "description": "fieldNorm(doc=0)"
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "value": 0.5,
                     "description": "coord(1/2)"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_shard": 3,
            "_node": "ZTZ37EpAR1W9e4Qqwk0O5Q",
            "_index": "index_for_test",
            "_type": "business",
            "_id": "1203656733",
            "_score": 0.023267403,
            "_source": {
               "name": "چمن",
               "categories": [
                  "پیتزا"
               ]
            },
            "_explanation": {
               "value": 0.023267403,
               "description": "product of:",
               "details": [
                  {
                     "value": 0.046534806,
                     "description": "sum of:",
                     "details": [
                        {
                           "value": 0.046534806,
                           "description": "weight(categories:پیتزا in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                           "details": [
                              {
                                 "value": 0.046534806,
                                 "description": "score(doc=0,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
                                 "details": [
                                    {
                                       "value": 0.15165187,
                                       "description": "queryWeight, product of:",
                                       "details": [
                                          {
                                             "value": 0.30685282,
                                             "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)"
                                          },
                                          {
                                             "value": 0.49421698,
                                             "description": "queryNorm"
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "value": 0.30685282,
                                       "description": "fieldWeight in 0, product of:",
                                       "details": [
                                          {
                                             "value": 1,
                                             "description": "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                             "details": [
                                                {
                                                   "value": 1,
                                                   "description": "termFreq=1.0"
                                                }
                                             ]
                                          },
                                          {
                                             "value": 0.30685282,
                                             "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)"
                                          },
                                          {
                                             "value": 1,
                                             "description": "fieldNorm(doc=0)"
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "value": 0.5,
                     "description": "coord(1/2)"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost isn't being ignored...you're just adding a fuzzy component to the score, which is changing the overall ordering.  If you run the queries with `?explain=true`, you'll get a debug dump of how the score is being constructed.

With your first query, exact matches were required.  Combined with the `most_fields`, scoring is relatively simple:  find the document that has the most exact matches in the most number of fields.

Your second query introduces fuzziness with two edits.  This means that any word which is within two character edits will match.  This can drastically change the number of matching tokens.

If you post the `explain` debug output, I can help analyze it to give you a clearer explanation, but basically the answer is:  boosting is still working, your scores just changed because of the fuzzy matching.

Comment: thank you for your response, my requirment is showing exaxtly like first result but also support fuzziness. would you help me how can I achive this result?

Comment: You could try doing a bool combination of a regular `multi_match` and a fuzzy `multi_match`.  If you boost the regular over the fuzzy, it will prefer exact matches in the rankings but also give you fuzzy results further down.

Answer (score 2):

As Zach offered I change my query to this to achieve my result:

```
GET /index_for_test/_search
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "multi_match": {
            "query":       "Italian",
            "type":        "most_fields",
            "fields":      [ "name^2", "categories" ],
            "boost":10
          }
          },
          {
            "multi_match": {
            "query":       "Italian",
            "type":        "most_fields",
            "fields":      [ "name^2", "categories" ],
            "fuzziness":2
          }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```